# Sorting is different if sorted using Case statement in Order By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am executing 2 different SQL Queries, To me they should produce the same results, but its not. The sort order changes in the second query. Just Wondering why its happening?

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ServiceDate
    ,ServiceTime
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SortProfile = 'Y'
            THEN SortOrder1
        ELSE SortOrder2
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SortProfile = 'N'
            THEN SortOrder2
        ELSE SortOrder1
        END
    ,Price DESC
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code    Date        Time        Price   SortProfile SortOrder2   SortOrder1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
38424   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               14              9
38440   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               14              9
41892   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              13
38436   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              11
18228   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              15


SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ServiceDate
    ,ServiceTime
    ,SortOrder2
    ,Price DESC

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code    Date        Time        Price   SortProfile SortOrder2     SortOrder1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
38424   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               14              9
38440   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               14              9
18228   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              15
38436   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              11
41892   02/10/2015  13:12:00    0       N               25              13
```

Comment: It's producing the same result but in different order. You are saying `To me they should produce the same results, but its not` both are different things so what's the problem .....'ordering` or `result` issue ?

Comment: The results from your second query on the CTE seem dubious to me, partly because the sort order for the `SortOrderTwo` column make no sense, whether those data are sorted as numbers or even as text.

Comment: @Susang I meant Ordering issue

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, My mistake. I have edited the question now

Comment: Please provide some test data,i am not able to repro the issue with the given data(assuming it is test data)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the test data. also I noticed sorting on codes columns is affected If I try to move the JOIN.

Comment: If multiple rows have identical values for all columns/expressions mentioned in the `ORDER BY` clause, then the order that those rows are returned in is not well defined. That seems to be the case here. If you want deterministic ordering, you have to provide sufficient expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause such that each row yields a unique set of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
To me they should produce the same results, but its not
```

Both of the results are correct as the last 3 rows have **the same** values in the sorting columns, so any order within these 3 rows is acceptable.

The differnce that you see is explained by **different** `execution plans` for these 2 queries (they are different because one of them contains `SortOrder1` in `order by` and other not).

When the server elaborates `execution plan` it has no idea if your query will or will not return the rows with "Y" so it consider `SortOrder1` and it use it in sort for the first plan and don't use in the second.

You can prove it to yourself looking at both execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from CTE
order by SortProfile ,
case when SortProfile  = 'Y' then SortOrderOne 
     else case when SortProfile = 'N' then SortOrdertwo 
          end
end DESC,
case when SortProfile  = 'Y' then SortOrdertwo
     else case when SortProfile = 'N' then SortOrderOne 
          end
end DESC
```

output is:

```
SortOrderOne    SortOrderTwo    SortProfile
14              9               N         
14              9               N         
25              15              Y         
25              13              Y         
25              11              Y
```

Answer (score 0):

in the 1st Sort, you don't need the following 2 order by cases

```
WHEN SortProfile = 'Y'
        THEN SortOrder1
    ELSE SortOrder2
    END
,CASE 
    WHEN SortProfile = 'N'
        THEN SortOrder2
    ELSE SortOrder1
    END
```

use any one of them because of they produce the same result.

Also, it seems that the columns are ordered correctly as per the order by condition as all the columns in your order by are sorted correctly. Just add the column [code] in the order by condition to get the same result. I think that might solve the issue